# JQuery Autocomplete Not showing on Page

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am having issues getting this JQuery AJAX to show on the web page.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".autocomp").autocomplete(
         {
             source: function( request, response ) {
                         $.ajax({
                              url: "/apples",
                              dataType: "json",
                              data: {
                                 srch:request.term
                              },
                              success: function( data ) {
                                   response( $.map( data.result, function( item ) {
                                       return {
                                          label: item.name,    
                                          value: item.name,
                                          data: item
                                        };
                                    }));
                               }
                          });
                     },
                     minLength: 2,
                     select: function(event, ui){
                                  var parts = this.name.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);
                                  $("key_"+parts[2]).val(ui.item.data.key);
                               }
                    }); 
});
```

The function calls a website that returns the information:  `{result: [{name:macintosh,key:1},{name:golden,key:2},{name:fuji,key:3}]}`. 
The Object sent back in the data field is:

```
Object {result= [Object{name:macintosh,key:1},Object{name:golden,key:2},Object{name:fuji,key:3}]}
```

The HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="name_1" id="name_1" class="autocomp"><input type="hidden" name="key_1" id="key_1">
```

Anyone have an idea why it is not working?  I am importing

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and the style sheet:

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have missing `http:` where you are linking jquery

Comment: it should be `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Can you show the printout of what gets returned when you hit the "/apples" endpoint?

Comment: I added that below the call to show what is returned.  it's Object{result=[Object{name...}]} etc

Comment: Are there any errors on the page?

Comment: None - It just doesn't show up at all.  No pop-up/drop-down visible.  I even put an alert statement to see if it worked and it was returning the correct information.  So I know we are getting through the return part, just nothing is displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is from the WebTuts site.  it works now, but it does not use the AJAX call - which I would still LOVE to know how to do.  It is a solution and gets the same result done, but does not explicitly answer the question of how to use AJAX with it.  Replace the $.ajax section with this seciton.

```
$.getJSON("/apples?srch="+request.term,request,
                        function(data){
                            var names = [];
                            $.each(data.result, function(i, val){
                                names.push({
                                    label: val.name,
                                    value: val.name,
                                    data: val
                                });
                            });
                            response(names);
                        });
```

Thanks all!
Jon

Comment: I have heard that this code might open people up to an SQL injection attack.  How would this happen in the code?